# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ingredients.map')

Tags: react-native, jsx

Ingredients should be an object containing a list of ingredients with properties. But when using ingredients.map, it returns the " undefined is not an object( evaluating 'ingredients.map')" error and makes the console.log(recipeData2 suddenly does not return anything anymore).

Why is this going wrong and how could I achieve my goal? I am trying to print the name of every ingredient in the ingredients.

```js
export default function DetailPage ({navigation, route} : any) {
    const [recipeData2, setrecipeData2] = useState<Recipe_detail[] | null>([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
    const [key, setKey] = useState<string>('API KEY HERE');


    const {id} = route.params;

    const getrecipeData2 = async() => {
        setLoading(true);
        const url = 'https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/' + id + '/information?apiKey=' + key + '&includeNutrition=false';
        axios.get(url).then(function (response) {
            setrecipeData2(response.data);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            if(error) console.log('error')
        }).finally(function () {
            setLoading(false);
        })
    }
    console.log(recipeData2);// this suddenly returns undefined when the .map function is added to the code

    useEffect(() => {
        getrecipeData2();
    }, [id])

    function handleOnPress() {
        setrecipeData2(null)
        navigation.navigate('Home')
    }

    const ingredients = recipeData2?.extendedIngredients ;
    console.log(ingredients);// this returns what i need so i know it works

    //this is the function in question that breaks everything
    const ingredientsJSX = ingredients.map((item, index) => {
    })


    return (
      <View>
          <Button title="back" onPress={handleOnPress}/>
          <Text>{recipeData2?.title}</Text>
          <Text>{recipeData2?.summary}</Text>
          <Text>{recipeData2?.instructions}</Text>
      </View>
    )
}
```